# Spells of Dunedain - Tolkien

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

I need someone well versed in Tolkien books and all writings.

Is there a Elven/Vala/Maiar spell to bind Nazgul to the Void and trap them?

Comment: Why, are you currently being chased by one?

Comment: Spells don't work the same way in Middle Earth as in Hogwarts

Comment: Im asking a tolkien related, I have some books but looking for specific wrtting on Dunedain spells, Nazgul Demise and how to defeat them permanently.

Comment: what good would an elven/Vala/Maiar "spell" do a Dunedain, who is none of the above?

Comment: Does LOTR even *have* spells?

Comment: @SystemDown: "I once knew every spell in all the tongues of Elves or Men or Orcs that was ever used for such a purpose."

Comment: @JimmyShelter - that just means that **if any existed**, he knew them...

Comment: @Oldcat - of course they would also be useless against Nazgul.  Unless you needed to go through a locked door to get away from one.

Comment: @DVK - very good, although Nazgullus Dispellarium might be more useful.

Comment: Even though the user no longer is on the site I want to say that (Unfinished Tales?) that's what happened with Gollum: he went into the Mines of Moria exactly to avoid the Nazgûl so in fact yes that would be a good reason to be able to open the doors.

Comment: The only way they can be destroyed (with the exception of the blades Westernesse as noted below) is the destruction of the One Ring. And even then there is 'destroyed' and 'destroyed' as described about the Witch-king of Angmar. Yet Tolkien also noted that the Nazgûl aren't a problem to the fearless. But on the subject of trapping they also exist in the Unseen already anyway so why would that matter?

Answer (score 8):

Middle-earth certainly does have spells; remember Gandalf's statement that he "*once knew every spell in all the tongues of Elves or Men or Orcs that was ever used for such a
purpose*" at the doors of Moria.

However, Tolkien never actually wrote out a spell book, or even a spell list.

We can infer from his writings that spells exist for opening doors, for enchanting swords (and wolf-headed battering rams), and for protecting buried treasure, as well as something called a "Word of Command".  There are also shutting-spells (Gandalf uses one at the Chamber of Mazarbul) and counter-spells (the Balrog uses one back at him in the same scene).  Gandalf even throws lightning-bolts about a few times, sets fire to stuff, and can cast light from his staff.

"Spell" is also used as a general term for being under the enchantment of someone or something, such as the Hobbits at Bombadil's or in the Barrow.  Saruman's Voice is this kind of spell.

If you're currently being hunted by a Nazgul and you don't feel that your wits, luck or courage are up to the job (which in Tolkien's world means you probably don't stand much chance to begin with), and if Glorfindel isn't around to help you fight him off, your best bet is to get hold of a sword from the Barrow.  These were enchanted by the Dunedain, which seems to meet one of your requirements:

> Doubtless the Orcs despoiled them, but feared to keep the knives, knowing them for what they are: work of Westernesse, wound about with spells for the bane of Mordor.

And they are capable of destroying Nazgul, which meets your main requirement:

> No other blade, not though mightier hands had wielded it, would have dealt that foe a wound so bitter, cleaving the undead flesh, breaking the spell that knit his unseen sinews to his will.

However they seem to be more potent at breaking the spell that makes a Nazgul in the first place, rather than having any kind of direct magical effect on them.  So using one would involve having to go toe-to-toe with a Nazgul, which it seems to me is not a good position to find oneself in.

Tolkien, of course, never wrote anything more explicit about just *what spell* was on those swords, thus giving us ample fuel for internet discussion 60 years later.  You'd almost think he knew.

Comment: These days, with the One Ring gone and all, the Nazguls are all gone anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped I found the solution in the very nature of evil and good, evil is one paced, good is twice paced hence the oppening to defeat them.

Comment: **'If you're currently being hunted by a Nazgul and you don't feel that your wits, luck or courage are up to the job (which in Tolkien's world means you probably don't stand much chance to begin with)'** Correct, really, because Tolkien stated in a letter that they only are a problem to those with fears. Not to say they couldn't hurt them but the Nazgûl have no power over the fearless.